# Servlet mapping for ajax call parameters

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, jsonp

I have ajax calls that have the url http://localhost:80/Push/GetContacts?id=23 and the following servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/GetContacts*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet does not get invoked on ajax calls. It returns a HTTP 404 not found response. What is the right URL pattern for my ajax calls?

Here is the ajax call that is not working because of the servlet.

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/Push/GetContacts&callback=?', function(data) {
     alert(data.data);
});
```

The servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException{
        try{
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            out.write("{data: helloworld}");
            out.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url pattern needs to be just `/GetContacts` without the star. The parameters are not part of the servlet mapping and are ignored when finding the correct servlet. If you wanted to support an URL like `/GetContacts/23` you could use a servlet mapping for `/GetContacts/*` and retrieve the id using `request.getPathInfo`.

**Edit:** as BalusC just noticed, the url in your ajax call is incorrect. The parameter callback should be separated by a question mark, not an ampersand: `GetContacts?callback=...`

Also, `{data: helloworld}` is invalid according to the [json spec](http://json.org/), both data and helloworld should be enclosed in quotes. But that is also independent from the 404 problem.

Comment: I've already tested it. I open the browser with the url: http://localhost:80/Push/GetContacts?id=23 and 404 error comes up. But not with http://localhost:80/Push/GetContacts.

Comment: I'm trying to make a jsonp call so there is callback parameter

Comment: Do you have the source code of this servlet? Maybe the servlet actually gets called but then returns the 404 itself because it does not find the passed id. Debugging the servlet or adding some print statements there might help in that case.

Comment: Did you rebuild/redeploy/restart after changing the `web.xml`?

Comment: @Jörn: look above I added the servlet

Comment: Your ajax URL is wrong (and content type in servlet also, but that shouldn't generate a 404).

Comment: I still thins it is the servlet mapping that is wrong, becasue I tried with replacing the url pattern with "/*" and it worked but that is not a good solution though

Comment: Ok found the problem. Incorrect url in jsonp call. http://localhost:8080/Push/GetContacts?callback=?